# Unity3D Character glitching

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

Having trouble with a glitch in my Character and animator: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pigrfr98p7oscx3/IMG_1876.MOV?dl=0

I have a C# script that toggles between the pawn piece and the Humanoid figure. I have another script that handles the click to move motion that I will include:

```
public class MC : MonoBehaviour {

    private float speed = 10;                   //Speed of Player
    private Vector3 targetPosition;             //Location of MouseClick; where to move to
    private bool isMoving;                      //Check to see if moving
    Animator anim;                              //Animates Humanoid Piece

    void Start ()
    {
        targetPosition = transform.position;        //Current location
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();            //Gets Animator Controller attached to Piece
        isMoving = false;                   
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        //If the mouse is clicked
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
            //If piece is selected; not moved yet 
            anim.SetBool ("isSelected", true);
            SetTargetPosition ();
            //if we are still moving, then move the player
            if (isMoving) {
                MovePlayer ();
            }
        }
    }
    /// Sets the target position we will travel too.
    void SetTargetPosition()
    {
        Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        float point = 0f;

        if (plane.Raycast (ray, out point)) {
            targetPosition = ray.GetPoint (point);
        }

        //The humanoid piece is being moved
        isMoving = true;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the player in the right direction and also rotates them to look at the target position.
    /// When the player gets to the target position, stop them from moving.
    /// </summary>
    void MovePlayer()
    {
        transform.LookAt(targetPosition);

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards( transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        anim.SetBool ("isWalking", true);
        //if we are at the target position, then stop moving
        if(transform.position == targetPosition)
            isMoving = false;
    }
```

** EDIT: Adding a picture of the Animation Tree
[image: Adding a picture of the Animation Tree]

Comment: Can you provide an idea of what the animation is supposed to look like? Also, what does the animator tree look like when this is occurring? How does its state progress?

Comment: We'll need more information than just "Having trouble with a glitch in my Character and animator". What do you mean by a glitch? What are the animator and character doing wrong?

Comment: @Alox I put the video (the dropbox link) to better explain what the glitch is. The expected animation is when it's transitioned from the basic chess piece to a humanoid, it should do a screaming motion. The on click, it should walk over to where the mouse was clicked and slash that place.

Comment: @Serlite, I just added a picture and what the transitions represent